# The member with identity '' does not exist in the metadata collection. Parameter name: identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, linq-to-entities

I am getting the exception while adding object in database (Sqlite I am currently using).

Exception: The member with identity '' does not exist in the metadata collection. Parameter name: identity

Normally this code works on my local  but I want to  run this project my netbook too but whatever I do I cant find the way  which make it run.

Any help will be greately  appreciated.

```
   -- Original table schema
    CREATE TABLE [Content] (
        [Id] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        [Title] text NOT NULL,
        [Content] text NOT NULL,
        [PageId] integer NOT NULL,
        [CreatedAt] datetime,
        [UpdatedAt] datetime,
        [CreatedBy] text,
        [UpdatedBy] text,
        CONSTRAINT [FK_Content_PageId_Page_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([PageId]) REFERENCES [Page] ([Id])
    );
    -- Original table schema
    CREATE TABLE [Page] (
        [Id] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        [Title] text NOT NULL,
        [Url] text NOT NULL,
        [Visibility] bit NOT NULL,
        [CreatedAt] datetime,
        [UpdatedAt] datetime,
        [CreatedBy] text,
        [UpdatedBy] text
    );



    using (var entities = new PageEntities())
                {
                    var page = entities.Pages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
                    if (page != null)
                    {
                        var content = new Content
                                          {
                                              Title = model.Title,
                                              Explanation = model.Explanation,
                                              CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                                              UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                                              PageId = page.Id
                                          };
                        entities.AddToContents(content);
                        entities.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("PageContent/" + id, "Admin");


        }
```